# Link of <code> not rendering correctly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, rendering

Example: [`and(int first, int second)`][1]

[1]: http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.0/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#and(int, int)

It's rendered correctly in edit preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is a problem, you will need to encode that space. Spaces are not allowed in URLs.

Comment: Yes, change space in URL to %20 then it works.